# loginout function customization

Tags: functions, customization, users, login

I want to make `login / logout` function inside my header to display when the user is logged in **Logged in as,{user name}** where **{user name}** should be wrapped inside an anchor tag with a custom permalink inside the `href` attribute.

I've found this function `<?php wp_loginout( $redirect, $echo ); ?>` but I do not know if it's possible to modify this function to do what I need.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how can I do this ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a logged in conditional. From the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in), you might be able to try in your theme (untested):

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $current_user->user_firstname;
}
?>
```

---

**EDIT**

After consulting the [WP Codex on the topic](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo), I was able to display my user's identity using the following:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $user_identity;
    get_currentuserinfo();  
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $user_identity;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't display, the user name, just "Logged in as, "

Comment: I updated the answer with a tested solution. Hope that helps.